# C++ project not compiling, errors are in previously functioning third party header file that also has nothing to do with the changes

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Are there any tips/guidelines/recommended routes to go, when trying to figure out why something like this is happening? I'm using Visual Studio 2019, I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, restarting VS 2019. Nothing is working. My coworker is using the same branch as me and it works on their machine. When I checkout the branch, my VS won't compile it, citing errors in an unrelated third party header file neither of us have touched, and the source file we've touched doesn't interact or need it in anyway, doesn't include it either. The errors themselves are complete junk too:

(line 75) syntax error: 'constant'

(line 75) unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

(line 81) syntax error: 'constant'

(line 81) unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

```
    /** The minimum priority that a thread can have. */
    static const int MIN_PRIORITY = 1; //This is the line 75 its claiming errors on

    /** The default priority that a thread is given at create time. */
    static const int NORM_PRIORITY = 5;

    /** The maximum priority that a thread can have. */
    static const int MAX_PRIORITY = 10; //This is line 81
```

Before this, I also had it yell at me for a missing semicolon... on an include... so I added one and then removed it and it stopped displaying the nonsense errors related to that.

I was hoping someone could offer generalized advice to diagnosing or flushing out these weird nonsense compilation errors. I'm going to try restarting my laptop next

Edit: restarting my PC did not help. If I rename MIN_PRIORITY and MAX_PRIORITY it builds... so I guess I can continue my work for now hoping those renames don't break anything else in my project

Comment: Before you started to get errors, what changes have you made? Either to your own source of to the third-party library you're using? If you look at the commit history what does it show? What are the differences?

Comment: It could be some garbage before line 75, even in other files that include this one or are included by this one. It could even be commandline arguments. Please extract a [mcve], you'll probably find the error yourself doing so.

Comment: How many times to repeat - using all UPPERCASE identifiers for compile time constant is a bad idea and antipattern.

Comment: I didn't write the header! :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, `syntax error: 'constant'` on MSVC is almost always some mysterious Windows macro that `#define`s a common identifier to some literal value.

For example, I wouldn't be surprised if in *some* Windows header there exists something like `#define MIN_PRIORITY 0`, which would cause your first line to turn into `static const int 0 = 1;`.

To make things worse, this behavior entirely depends on the overall order that the preprocessor sees `#include`s.  Changing include order in one file can cause entirely unrelated code to break.

To solve this, I usually open the file in Visual Studio and Ctrl-click the identifier that the compiler error is complaining about.  If you are lucky, it will jump you directly to where that macro is defined.  If you are unlucky and it doesn't jump you to the source, you can tell the compiler to only run the preprocessor phase, then see if there is a literal value in place of your identifier.  Then you will have to do some digging to figure out where that value comes from.

Once you find the source, you have to figure out how to work around it - some Windows headers have special values that you can define to disable certain macros, such as `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`.  In other cases you can manually `#undef` the colliding macros - however beware that other code may rely on the macro you removed.  If neither of those will work, you will have to change your identifier to stop colliding with Windows.

In short, legacy Windows headers are awful and will mangle your code without your permission.  But they can't change them at this point because too much code relies on the current behavior.

Comment: And this is one of the reasons ALLCAPS should be reserved for use with macros. In the old days I would have said constants, but now that we have many different types of constants and only one of them, the macro, has this sort of nasty side effect, we need to get a bit more explicit.

Comment: I've updated my post to reflect that renaming the two fixes it, so you might be right. Thank you, I'm going to try your suggestion

Comment: Winspool.h:323 has `#define MIN_PRIORITY  1`